# Powershell: Remove Module does not unload global [constant] variables defined in a nested module

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have a Module Manifest File [.psd1 file] via which I import **nested modules** [.psm1 files]. One of the modules [.psm1] file defines a **constant** variable in global scope like this -

```
set-variable -name DataDirectory -option Constant -value "DataSources" -scope global -description "Data Directory"
```

When I do **remove-module** of the psd1 file & then again try to do a **import-module** in the same session of the Powershell ISE, I get the following error -

```
+ set-variable <<<<  -name DataDirectory -option Constant -value "DataSources" -scope global -description "Data Directory"
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (DataDirectory:String) [Set-Variable], SessionStateUnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : VariableNotWritable,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetVariableCommand
```

which means that the variables defined in one of the nested modules have not been unloaded.

Do I have to explicit do a remove-variable ? I thought remove-module will unload everything

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Remove-Module` will unload everything defined in the module scope. Only the module that defined the variable can remove it. Global variables will not remove when the module is unloaded. In addition, outside the module scope, you cannot remove a constant variable with `Remove-Variable`.  One thing you can try is testing if the variable already exist before you try creating it.

Comment: You said - Only the module that defined the variable can remove it. How can I achieve this ?

Comment: Don't scope it as global, it has to be defined in the module scope, just remove the global modifier. Youll have to find another solution if you did that so other modules can have access to it